# Just a new guy who needs some assistance

Tags: python, python-3.4

---

So i just finished writing this really basic script that just takes in names and values and puts them in a dictionary and displays them afterwards, nothing much, but i'm facing some problems, and i think the problem is from the add() function but i'm not really sure. Like i said i'm new to this... so please just run the code n give me all criticism.. i need it. thanks 
Code:

```
from time import sleep #To set delay time in the code or portions of the code

def dict_create():
 # Creates the _info dictionary by entering the _name keys & _score values 
  _info={}
  _info[_name]=_score
  print ('\n',_subject, 'class students names and scores',_info.items())



def reject():
  # Creates gateway for more() & dict() exec.
  confirm=input(" \nYOU WILL NO LONGER BE ABLE TO ADD MORE NAMES \n\n ['yes' to quit or 'no' to continue] :")

if confirm=='no':
    print ('\nBelow are the names and scores of all students offering ' + _subject )
    print ('\nProcessing...')
    sleep(1)
    dict_create()
    _more()

elif confirm=='yes':
    print ('\n',_subject, 'class students names and scores',_info.items())
    quit

else:
    print('\nInvalid input')
    reject()

def add():
     # Creates gateway for _info.dict.update...[This seems to be the problem]
    _add=input('\n [+] Add more names [Yes or No] :')
    name=str(input ('\n [+] Please input students name :'))
    score=int(input ('\n [+] Please input students score :'))
    sleep(1)
    # Update process for student.dict 
    repeat={}
    repeat[name]=score
    _info.update(repeat)
    _more()

    if _add=='yes':
         _more()
    elif _add=='no':
         reject()
    else:
         print('\nSorry, invalid input, NOTE  INPUT IS CASE SENSITIVE')
         add()


def _more():
  # Creates gateway for 'more' validation
  if more=='no':
      reject()

  elif more=='yes':
      add()

  else:
     print('\nInvalid input.Please note your input is case sensitive.')
     _more()


# __init__
print('\nTHIS SCRIPTS GROUPS ALL NAMES & SCORES OF STUDENTS IN A CLASS')
_subject=input('\n [+] Input subject :')
_name=input('\n [+] Input students name :')
_score=float(input('\n [+] input students score :'))
print ('\nProcessing...')
sleep(1)
_info={}
_info[_name]=_score
more=input('\n [+] Do you want add more names [yes or no] :')
dict_create()
_more()
```

Thank you

Comment: Edit your title. Use it for something meaningful! Also: if you got errors, describe those errors including what you want to see.

Answer (score 0):

I rewrote your code and made a few changes. First of all I used `raw_input()` instead of `input()` because `input()` refers to a variable or something similar but isn't returning a string. `raw_input()` returns a string... So, I corrected a few of your functions to avoid errors (eg. when I got asked if I would like to enter another name and I entered "no" he asked me for another name and score.)

Okay so here is your modificated code:

```
from time import sleep #To set delay time in the code or portions of the code

def dict_create():
 # Creates the _info dictionary by entering the _name keys & _score values 
  _info={}
  _info[_name]=_score
  print ('\n',_subject, 'class students names and scores',_info.items())



def reject():
  # Creates gateway for more() & dict() exec.
  confirm=raw_input(" \nYOU WILL NO LONGER BE ABLE TO ADD MORE NAMES \n\n ['yes' to quit or 'no' to continue] :")

  if confirm=='no':
    print ('\nBelow are the names and scores of all students offering ' + _subject )
    print ('\nProcessing...')
    sleep(1)
    dict_create()
    _more()

  elif confirm=='yes':
    print ('\n',_subject, 'class students names and scores',_info.items())
    quit

  else:
    print('\nInvalid input')
    reject()

def add():
     # Creates gateway for _info.dict.update...[This seems to be the problem]
    _add=raw_input('\n [+] Add more names [Yes or No] :')
    name=str(raw_input ('\n [+] Please input students name :'))
    score=int(raw_input ('\n [+] Please input students score :'))
    sleep(1)
    # Update process for student.dict 
    repeat={}
    repeat[name]=score
    _info.update(repeat)
    _more()

    if _add=='yes':
         _more()
    elif _add=='no':
         reject()
    else:
         print('\nSorry, invalid input, NOTE  INPUT IS CASE SENSITIVE')
         add()


def _more():
  # Creates gateway for 'more' validation
  more=raw_input('\n [+] Do you want add more names [yes or no] :')

  if more=='no':
      reject()

  elif more=='yes':
      add()

  else:
     print('\nInvalid input.Please note your input is case sensitive.')
     _more()



# __init__
print('\nTHIS SCRIPTS GROUPS ALL NAMES & SCORES OF STUDENTS IN A CLASS')
_subject=raw_input('\n [+] Input subject :')
_name=raw_input('\n [+] Input students name :')
_score=float(raw_input('\n [+] input students score :'))
print ('\nProcessing...')
sleep(1)
_info={}
_info[_name]=_score
dict_create()
_more()
```